# Cannot create inference because there is no model on this pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a pipeline in the Designer tool from Azure Machine Learning Studio Preview. I am trying to run this pipeline as a batch prediction, due to the size of my input/output datasets.

The problem is that when I click on "Create Inference Pipeline"->"Batch Inference Pipeline" it returns the below error message (highlighted in red):
[image]

I tried to check the microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-run-batch-predictions-designer), but I didn't find nothing related to that error.